# DRF detail route without a PK

Tags: django-rest-framework

I’d like to create a detail route that renders the data of the current user.

If I use a custom router:

```
class CustomRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomRouter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.routes.append(
            routers.Route(url=r'^{prefix}/current{trailing_slash}',
                          mapping={'get': 'current'},
                          name='{basename}-current',
                          initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}))


rest_router = CustomRouter()
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(rest_router.urls)),
]
```

it works, and I can access my logged in user at `/api/users/current/`.

However, if I use my `CustomUser` and register the my whole `UserViewSet` (which descends from `viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet`):

```
rest_router.register(r'users', viewsets.UserViewSet)
```

my `current/` route stops working. Is there a way I can add such a custom detail route that doesn’t require a pk?

**Edit**: my second approach was to add a `@list_route` that actually returns only one object instead of one. This doesn’t require a custom router at all, just an extra method on my `UserViewSet`:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    …
    @list_route(methods=['get'])
    def current(self, request):
        return Response(self.serializer_class(request.user).data)
```

This, however, is pretty ugly for obvious reasons: why would I return one object in a list route?

Comment: Any route without a PK becomes a list route by definition. If you remove the 'pk' part form the detail route in DefaultRouter, it'll be the same as a list route.

Comment: I know that. The problem is, I actually need a detail route, but with a fixed PK (the ID of the logged in user). But if I create a `@detail_route`, I must call it as `api/users/current/1` where 1 could be any number.

Comment: but you could have multiple users right? so the pk would actually vary. Whether the pk supplied actually corresponds to a logged in user is upto your permission classes to determine.

Comment: Yes, but from the request's point of view it is fixed. Thus, I don’t want to put it in the URL as such.